Next 13 server props
In Next 13, I have a list of products with categories. I want to put these categories into constants so I can check if a product belongs to one category or another. For example:
if (product.id === CONSTANTS.DRINKS) { //do something with the product if it is from the drinks category }
These constants would be populated upon a request to an external API. They must be filled in throughout the code and will be used in both common javascript files and React components. Is there a way to do this in the next 13? Considering that there are files that are rendered on the server and other files that use RTK that will be rendered on the client. Is there another approach to distributing these constants throughout the code?
I tried to make a request to the API to fill in the constants, but as there are files that are rendered on the server and others on the client, it didn't work as I expected. They must only be filled once and all code will be able to see this value filled.

With this reference:
if (product.id === CONSTANTS.DRINKS) { };

I assume you must've meant for something like:
if (product.type === CONSTANTS.DRINK_TYPE) {
   // check if it's a "drink"
}

/**
* or...
*/

if (constants.DRINKS.includes(product.id)) {
   // check if this product ID is apart of a constant array of drinks?
};


The way I would go about this would be using some sort of data schema/models/tables that work with the server side, like Prisma with Vercel Postgres (highly recommended if you're using vercel to deploy).
While you don't have to use that method specifically for data management, the same concept applies:
With prisma, for example, a prisma.schema set up that would benefit this target:
// config / set-up example:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL")
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
}

// the "constant" types
enum ConstantType {
  DRINK
  FOOD
  // ...
}

// the product

model Product {
  id           String       @id @default(uuid())
  constantType ConstantType @default(DRINK)
  /**
  * createdAt    DateTime     @default(now())
  * updatedAt    DateTime     @default(now())
  * ...
  */
}

This would allow each product to have a designated "type" which you can check for.
import { Product, ConstantType } from "@prisma/client";

const checkProductType = (product: Product) => {
   if (product.constantType === ConstantType.DRINK) { };
}

I do recommend integrating with prisma & vercel postgres (personally), but you can accomplish the same goal with any database system you'd choose to use.
